# Rotate QGraphicsCustomItem into a QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, rotation, qgraphicsitem

i'm a newbie with c++ and QT, but i've trying to learn as much as i can

i've created a simple class (called MainWindow) and with Qt Creator (Qt 5.10.0) i set a QGraphicsView into the Mainwindows.ui

inside the Mainwindow costructor i've created a QGraphicScene (linked to the QGraphicsView item) that i would like to populate with some QGraphicsRecItems.

This RecItems must to be rotated with their center point, with a given "Alpha".

I've read tons of docs, tryed lots of example, but they still rotate with the painter origin e not their center point.

Can someone give me a simple example to achive this?

Also, i would like to set the origin on the lower left point for the QGraphicView.

Thanks

i've created a custom Graphic item because i want to create a rectangle with a text inside of it.

So: this is the header called "areagrafica.h":

```
#ifndef AREAGRAFICA_H
#define AREAGRAFICA_H

#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPen>
#include <moduledata.h>


class Grafica_PPU : public QGraphicsItem
{
  public:
    Grafica_PPU(QString ModuleName, GraphicModuleData tmpInfoGrafiche, QPen Pen, qreal tmpAlpha);


    QRectF boundingRect() const;

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,QWidget *widget);

    private:
        GraphicModuleData infoGrafiche;
        qreal Alpha,xc,yc;

        QString Testo;

        QPen Penna;

};
#endif // AREAGRAFICA_H
```

and this is the "areagrafica.cpp"

```
#include "areagrafica.h"


Grafica_PPU::Grafica_PPU(QString ModuleName, GraphicModuleData tmpInfoGrafiche, QPen Pen, qreal tmpAlpha)
{
    infoGrafiche = tmpInfoGrafiche;
    Penna = Pen;
    Testo = ModuleName;
    Alpha = tmpAlpha;
}

QRectF Grafica_PPU::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(infoGrafiche.posX,infoGrafiche.posY,infoGrafiche.Width,infoGrafiche.Height);
}

void Grafica_PPU::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
           QWidget *widget)
{
    //Penna.setWidth(5);

    painter->setPen(Penna);


    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing); //Ottengo bordi senza spingoli
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::TextAntialiasing); //Miglioro la lettura del testo ruotato

    painter->translate(QPoint(infoGrafiche.xC,infoGrafiche.yC));
    //painter->scale(1.0, -1.0);
    painter->rotate(Alpha);

    painter->drawRect(boundingRect()); //Disegno il bordo di dimensioni scelte
    painter->drawPoint(boundingRect().center());
    painter->drawText(boundingRect(),Qt::AlignCenter,Testo); //Creo un testo avente dimensione uguale alla dimensione del modulo, con il testo allineato al centro


   // update();
}
```

Inside the main class i use this:

```
 Grafica_PPU *test,*test2;
    GraphicModuleData tmp;
    tmp.posX = 45;
    tmp.posY = -100;
    tmp.Height = 22;
    tmp.Width = 54;


    test = new Grafica_PPU("PP55103",tmp,*Grafico_Matita_Nera,0.0);
    test2 = new Grafica_PPU("PP55103",tmp,*Grafico_Matita_Nera,0.0);

    Grafico_Scena->addItem(test);
    Grafico_Scena->addItem(test2);
```

where "Grafico_Matita_Nera" is a Pen and "Grafico_Scena" is the scene

Comment: Did you try to [set the transformation origin point](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setTransformOriginPoint)?

Comment: yes, but nothing change

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to establish the origin of the transformations in the center of the rectangle as shown below:

```
QGraphicsRectItem *r = {...}
r->setTransformOriginPoint(r->rect().center());
r->setRotation(some_value)
```

Example:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(new QGraphicsScene(-100, -100, 200, 200));

    QGraphicsRectItem *r = ui->graphicsView->scene()->addRect(0, 0, 60, 60, QPen(Qt::blue), QBrush(Qt::red));
    r->setTransformOriginPoint(r->rect().center());

    QVariantAnimation *animation = new QVariantAnimation(this);
    connect(animation, &QVariantAnimation::valueChanged, [r](QVariant value){
        r->setRotation(value.toReal());
    });
    animation->setStartValue(0);
    animation->setEndValue(360);
    animation->setDuration(1000);
    animation->setLoopCount(-1);
    animation->start();
}
```

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/48303751).

---

You do not have to rotate the `QPainter`, if you do not have to rotate the item for it you must use the center of `boundingRect()`

```
Grafica_PPU::Grafica_PPU(const QString &ModuleName, GraphicModuleData tmpInfoGrafiche, QPen Pen, qreal tmpAlpha)
{
    infoGrafiche = tmpInfoGrafiche;
    Penna = Pen;
    Testo = ModuleName;
    Alpha = tmpAlpha;
    setTransformOriginPoint(boundingRect().center());
    setRotation(Alpha);
}

QRectF Grafica_PPU::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(infoGrafiche.XC, infoGrafiche.YC,infoGrafiche.Width,infoGrafiche.Height);
}

void Grafica_PPU::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *,
           QWidget *)
{
    painter->setPen(Penna);
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing); //Ottengo bordi senza spingoli
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::TextAntialiasing); //Miglioro la lettura del testo ruotato
    painter->drawRect(boundingRect()); //Disegno il bordo di dimensioni scelte
    painter->drawPoint(boundingRect().center());
    painter->drawText(boundingRect(),Qt::AlignCenter,Testo); //Creo un testo avente dimensione uguale alla dimensione del modulo, con il testo allineato al centro

}
```

Example:

```
GraphicModuleData tmp{0, 0, 40, 40};
Grafica_PPU *item = new Grafica_PPU("test", tmp, QPen(Qt::red), 100);

GraphicModuleData tmp2{-50, 50, 60, 40};
Grafica_PPU *item2 = new Grafica_PPU("test", tmp2, QPen(Qt::red), 90);

ui->graphicsView->scene()->addItem(item);
ui->graphicsView->scene()->addItem(item2);
```

Output:

[image]

Plus:

comment: *is it possible to rotate the rectangle, but leave out the text?*

```
void Grafica_PPU::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *,
           QWidget *)
{
    painter->setPen(Penna);
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing); //Ottengo bordi senza spingoli
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::TextAntialiasing); //Miglioro la lettura del testo ruotato
    painter->drawRect(boundingRect()); //Disegno il bordo di dimensioni scelte
    painter->translate(boundingRect().center());
    painter->rotate(-rotation());
    painter->translate(-boundingRect().center());
    painter->drawText(boundingRect(),Qt::AlignCenter,Testo); //Creo un testo avente dimensione uguale alla dimensione del modulo, con il testo allineato al centro

}
```

[image]

Comment: if i've a custom QGraphicItem (see my post) i can't find  "rect().center()"

Comment: @PierluigiRovere what is GraphicModuleData?

Comment: is a simple struct with:  x,y,width, height

Comment: @PierluigiRovere It is one thing to rotate the item and another is to rotate the QPainter. What do you want to do?

Comment: i would like to rotate the item (rectangle+text), but i've tryied to rotate the painter because i didn't find other way

Comment: how can i use the boundingRect() center for the item rotation?

edit: i see right now your response. give me 1 min to try

Comment: @PierluigiRovere Check my code, there is the answer. If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct.

Comment: is it possible to rotate the rectangle, but leave out the text?

one solution could be to create a "rotated rectangle", insert it into the scene and add a text with out rotation, but i think there's a better way

Comment: @PierluigiRovere Yes, it is possible. I have added this code to the answer.

Comment: is... perfect!
but i would like to understand how it works: the translate move the origin into the rectangle (right?), after you "restore" the initial original position (before rotation"), but i don't understand why you redo the translate before adding the text.
Please, let me understand

Comment: last request:
could you give me some info for adding some QgraphicsItem child to my custom item?
i would like to insert some "circle" in a specific position into my custom item, and animate  each one with a change color   if a variable attached to each of them (pointers)  change to a specific value.

Comment: @PierluigiRovere Do you want to add an item that is a circle or do you only want to paint a circle? If you are going to do it, just pass the pointer of the item in the constructor: `QGraphicsEllipseItem* ellipse = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(pointer_of_item);`

Comment: The first option.
i'll try to dev.   Thanks!